# Nivo slider thumbs

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, nivo-slider

I'm using the nivo-slider and im trying to make thumbnails but I cant get it to work.

Here is what I have:

[Nino Slider Demo](http://ziimx.zeekoo.dk/slide/demo.html)

[Here is the tutorial on how to](http://dev7studios.com/blog/resources/using-thumbnails-with-the-nivo-slider/), but i cant get it to work.

[Nive Slider Website](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

I hope some one can see what i do wrong

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the theme 'default.css' conflicts with the img styling (as noted in their tutorial). You need to comment out the css styles in default.css for the following classes:

```
.theme-default .nivoSlider img
.theme-default .nivoSlider a
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav a
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav a.active
```

And, as noted in their [tutorial](http://dev7studios.com/resources/using-thumbnails-with-the-nivo-slider/), you need to add this styling:

```
#slider .nivo-controlNav {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-70px; /* Put the nav below the slider */
}
#slider .nivo-controlNav img {
    display:inline; /* Unhide the thumbnails */
    position:relative;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

I had trouble too with this, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I had lots of troubles finding where my thumbnails are as well. I finally found them by positionning them "absolute", and they finally appeared in the middle of the slideshow :)

But I don't really like the way they're displayed, so I made a quick fix which requires to edit the script a bit.

In jquery.nivo.slider.js, add this at the beginning of the file:

```
var thumbnails = $("#thumbnails"); // this is where your thumbnails will be
```

Then find this:

```
//Add Control nav
if(settings.controlNav){
    var nivoControl = $('<div class="nivo-controlNav"></div>');
    slider.append(nivoControl);
```

And replace with

```
//Add Control nav
if(settings.controlNav){
    var nivoControl = $('<div class="nivo-controlNav"></div>');
    thumbnails.append(nivoControl);
```

Find this:

```
$('.nivo-controlNav a', slider).live('click', function(){
```

Replace with:

```
$('.nivo-controlNav a', thumbnails).live('click', function(){
```

Then place a  somewhre in your page, and you're done :)

Of course, lots of improvements can be done, but as I said it's a quick fix. That would be nice if next versions of Nivo slider had an option to place the thumbnails in a different location.

Hope this helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Nivo site has a new demo that shows how the thumbnails work: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/

The relevant example has the following CSS styling:

```
#slider3 {
    margin-bottom:110px;
}
#slider3 .nivo-controlNav {
    position:absolute;
    left:185px;
    bottom:-70px;
}
#slider3 .nivo-controlNav a {
    display:inline;
}
#slider3 .nivo-controlNav img {
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:10px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #333;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #333;
}
#slider3 .nivo-controlNav a.active img {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Note how both the `a` and the `img` tag in the `.nivo-controlNav` class use `display: inline`, that is key to making it work.

The other properties are for positioning the nav bar and adding drop shadows.

Answer (score 0):

I had a great deal of difficulty getting image thumbnails to work properly myself.  This worked for me.  Full details at [my blog entry](http://www.setsailmedia.com/javascript/nivo-slider-and-image-thumbnails-solved/).

Add this CSS styling as the last to load (include it in a LINK beneath the other core Nivo CSS sheets)

```
.nivo-controlNav a {
display:inline; /* Display the thumbnail link element */
}

#slider .nivo-controlNav img {
display:inline; /* Un-hide the thumbnail image element */
position:relative;
margin: 10px 10px 0 0; /* Provide some white space around the thumbs */
}

#slider .nivo-controlNav {
position: absolute;
top: 600px; /* 600px is the height of our images in the slider */
}
```

And don't forget to set these parameters when you call Nivo:

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
controlNav:true, /* Display the control navigation */
controlNavThumbs:true, /* Display thumbnails */
controlNavThumbsFromRel:true, /* Source thumbnails from rel attribute */
});
```